# Check if Phonegap/Cordova app is playing audio/video

Tags: cordova, iframe, phonegap-plugins

How can I check if my Phonegap app is playing any media file?

In my Phonegap app page, I have an audio element as well as an iframe which plays video.

As soon as the user clicks on the video iframe, I want to pause the audio element, but cant track the iframe because of iframe restrictions.

That's why I want to check if Phonegap lets me know if app is playing media file.

Answer (score 1):

`Vimeo` and `YouTube` are providing a `Javascript API` to fit your use case. For example `YouTube`:

**HTML**

```
<script src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>
<!-- 1. The <iframe> (and video player) will replace this <div> tag. -->

<div id="player"></div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var player;

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
  player = new YT.Player('player', {
    height: '390',
    width: '640',
    videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
    events: {
      'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
    }
  });
}

function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
  if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {
    // Your function to stop your audio
    stopAudioPlaying();
  }
}

function stopAudioPlaying() {
  alert("STOP Playing Audio!")
}
```

[Relating Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mVjBeN)

API References: [Vimeo](https://developer.vimeo.com/player/js-api) & [YouTube iFrame API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference)

Comment: thanks for your answer..have tried this already..the youtube api is giving problems on android..

Comment: Than you have probably another issue not mentioned here.

Comment: have edited my question..what can i do if i m not limited to just youtube/vimeo videos and can have any video